# How can I reference the output of the first command when chaining Powershell commands

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

How can I extract one value from the first of a command chain in my output?  For example:

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice | Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics   | ft    UserDeviceAgent, Identity -a
```

The column UserDeviceAgent is visable in Get-ActiveSyncDevice, however I can't get it to appear in the final output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Get-ActiveSyncDevice | Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics   | ft DeviceUserAgent, Identity`

The attribute appears to be "DeviceUserAgent" and not "UserDeviceAgent".

Comment: Though this may be true, is there a way to back reference the attribute from the first command in the chain?